# Access selected value of drop down that was populated with query from a codebehind

Tags: jquery, asp.net, drop-down-menu, code-behind, selectedvalue

I've got a set of cascading drop downs that populate with JQuery ajax.
However when the user presses submit (at the end of the rest of the form) i need to post back and get the values of the drop downs. since they have been populated client side ASP.NET FREAKS OUT.

It tells me to make EnableEventValidation="false"

So i do that but it still doesn't get the correct value. It only gets a value that has been bound using the code behind.

Does anybody know how to access values of drop downs (or any input) that have been created outside of the code behind?

Comment: No real need to post the code, this is more conceptual than an actual debugging issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to read the POST value directly using the Request.Form or Request.Params collections. I think this circumvents the checking that ASP.NET does.

Comment: Interesting, how do you suggest I go about doing that?

Comment: Thanks Mate! Request.Form was perfect. Here is my resulting code: string[] countryVal = Request.Form.GetValues(ddCountry.UniqueID);

Answer (score 0):

there is a simple solution to this that i used earlier.
when you populate the dropdowns using clientside code the server freaks out because dropdowns arnt supposed to be adding new data. 
simply put a hidden textbox somewhere in the page add the values to it when ur adding them to the dropdowns then split the string on the server side to get the values and add them programatically to the dropdowns.

Comment: hmm clever. I'll use this if i can't find another solution as I'm not a fan of hidden controls. That will also give the server a bit more work todo, I'm on a fairly tight cpu usage at the moment, thats why I'm opting to use client side drop down control.